An obligation by law to report a car accident to the police
For the purposes of legal research, I would like to know if there are countries where there is an obligation by law to report a car accident (only collision, without casualties) to the police?
I know that Romania has such an obligation, are there any other countries?

Does it matter to you if the law is limited to participants in the crash, or are you looking for laws governing bystanders, as well?

ontario
Anyone in charge of a vehicle that is involved in an auto accident is required to report an auto accident to the police if anyone is injured or if the property damage is estimated to exceed $2000. Highway Traffic Act, s. 199.

united-states
From State-by-State Laws & Requirements for Reporting a Car Accident

Each state has its own set of rules for how, when, and if a car accident is required to be reported. It’s generally good practice to call local police and wait for them to come to the scene so that they can make an accident report.
...
Every state requires a DMV report for an accident where someone is injured or killed. But some states don’t require a report if the damages total less than a certain amount of money, and time limits vary for when reports need to be filed.


united-kingdom
The UK government states

Report a car accident with an animal
You must stop and report the accident to the police if you hit any:

dogs
horses
cattle, eg cows
pigs
goats
sheep
donkeys and mules

You must do this as quickly as you can, whether the animal is killed or not.

